# Can one prove by lack of contradiction?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

A proof by contradiction takes the form of if ~p then c, hence p. Or in other words, assume something is false, and if there is a contradiction that arises from this assumption, it must be true.

Can we also:

A) Assume something is true, and show by contradiction that it must be false

B) Assume something is true with a condition, for example, that a positive function is decreasing when its derivative is negative; then, show by *lack* of contradiction it is indeed true with said condition, outside of our assumption (a positive function is decreasing when its derivative is negative because the derivative is not positive). This might take the form of if p then ~c, hence p.

The first would be a rather elementary consequence of the second, but I am interested nonetheless. In particular, though, I'm curious as to whether B could be called circular reasoning.

Comment: I don't understand your second example ("if p then ~c, hence p"). If you assume p, then what is there left to prove? By that logic, I can let p be whatever I want, and choose c to be any false statement.

Comment: rage_man: Are you asking whether one can prove $p\to q$ by assuming both $p$ and $q$, and showing there is no contradiction?  If that's what you are asking, no, you cannot, because you will assumed what you are to prove.  To prove $p \to q$, you can assume $\lnot q$, and if you obtain $\lnot p$, then you will have proven $\lnot q \to \lnot p \equiv p \to q$.  That's proving the contrapositive.

Comment: @rage_man Perhaps by "lack of contradiction" you meant that "show it cannot be false"? In which case that basically means to show it is true.

Comment: @twosigma the example I provided may have muddied the waters. I meant that if I'm attempting to prove some claim of the form an object does something if a condition is true, can I assume it does the thing if the condition is true, and proceed to show that no contradiction arises from my assumption, thus it was valid to make that earlier assumption? And further, can this extend past "the assumption is valid" to saying the condition is indeed true?

Comment: @amWhy I believe I see your point -- so if q is implicated by p, the closest I can do to what I asked is assume one is false, then if I prove the other is false, I can show they must be true by contraposition?

Comment: @rage_man Unfortunately I still don't quite get what you're saying. When you say "to prove some claim of the form an object does something if a condition is true, can I assume it does the thing if the condition is true", this sounds to me like "to prove that $q$ is true if $p$ is true, assume $q$ is true if $p$ is true", which is just repeating yourself and assuming what you want to prove.

Comment: @twosigma right, can I then prove that assumption is correct if there is no contradiction, ie, nothing to tell me I was wrong to assume it was correct? And if that's the case, does that then imply that it is indeed correct? Or is this too circular?

Comment: What do you mean by "if there is no contradiction"? Be precise. How would you go about showing that? I think what you are talking about is to show that there are no counterexamples to whatever it is you want to prove; this is fine.

Comment: Meaning that if I assume both are true, for example, assume the object does indeed do a particular thing and assume separately the condition is true, can I prove it by reclaiming the earlier assumptions after a number of transformations. Or in other words, by exploring the assumptions and their implications, if I never encounter a contradiction which the assumptions would lead to, then it would lead me to believe that the assumptions were valid and it is correct that the object does the thing when the condition is true. However, this seems like it might be circular to me.

Comment: As a better example, take this toy case.

Theorem: a positive function $f$ is decreasing when its derivative is negative.

Proof: Assume $f$ is positive and decreasing, and its derivative is negative. Because its derivative opposes its sign, the rate of change opposes the function itself, and it is not increasing; therefore, $f$ is decreasing when it is positive and its derivative is negative.

Comment: Yes, but in your example, you did not actually *make use of* the assumption that $f$ is decreasing (which also happens to be what you want to prove). The problem happens when you make use of that assumption -- in which case it would be circular because you are saying that something is true in order to show that it is true.

Comment: Anyways, I recommend reading some book(s) on proofs and proof writing. They will likely help to clarify some of your questions.

Comment: Right, thank you for your correspondence. I think I have enough answers to piece together what I wish to know. If you want to leave some variation of what you said just above as an answer I would be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Sure. Generally speaking, proof by contradiction can refer to the strategy where you assume something to be false (or true), and then show that we get some contradiction, and therefore that the original assumption had to be true (or false). For example: Suppose you want to prove a statement of the form p. Then you could suppose that p is false, and reach some contradiction c, so you conclude that p must be true. On the other hand, instead of supposing that p is false, you could also suppose that ~p is true, which is equivalent, so it is really just a rephrasing of things.

However, some people take the definition of “proof by contradiction” more strictly, e.g. that you can only start by assuming something is false. In a sense this is fine and equivalent because you can always rephrase the statement “assume that ~q is true” by “assume that q is false”. In other words, you can rephrase the supposition that something is true by the supposition that its negation is false (and note that ~(~p) is equivalent to p). I think the important and practical thing to understand is that it doesn’t really matter what you call it; so long as you know what you are doing and using sound logic, you can do what you like — the remaining details are then merely a matter of clear writing, conciseness, “proper form”, etc (not to say these aren’t important, but I’d say they usually come secondary to being logically sound).

Also, there are different systems of logic (like intuitionistic logic, as was mentioned in another answer), and other sorts of subtleties, but I’m not referring to those, nor am I knowledgeable about them. You can explore an entire world about logic and set theory.

B) It sounds to me that you want to assume what you want to prove; this is circular. Let p be the thing you want to show, and let Cond be the condition you are referring to. Then it seems you are saying the following: to prove that Cond implies p, you want to *assume* that Cond does indeed imply p, and then “explore the implications” of this assumption, and, if you never reach a contradiction (whatever that means), your assumption must have been justified, in other words, you have “proved” what you wanted. Correct?

Well, consider the following: Let Cond be the statement “$x$ is a non-negative real number”, and let p be the statement “$x^2$ is negative”. I’m guessing that you might reason as follows: suppose that non-negative real numbers have negative squares. I’ll explore the implications of this assumption, and if I never reach a contradiction, then indeed my claim must have been true. But, wait, I can come up with a counterexample: 2 is non-negative, and 2^2 = 4 is positive, not negative. So, I reached a “contradiction”, and so my initial claim was false.

The problem with this line of reasoning is: What if you never came across this “contradiction”? Sometimes the claim at hand is a lot more complicated, and we don’t have any immediate obvious examples that might disprove our claim or we don’t have any known true statements that would conflict with our claim. Then in such a case, you couldn’t find a “contradiction”, but that doesn’t mean that one doesn’t exist. Also, if your initial claim is false, but you suppose it is true, then you can deduce anything. For that matter, why not just say “p is true, therefore p is true”. Or perhaps more subtly, we could have the following scenario: We suppose that p (which is actually false) is true. Then, we are able to deduce that q (which is also false) is true. And we can keep on going. For a silly example, suppose our claim is that $-1 > 0$ (suppose we don't know whether this is true or not). Now *assume* that $-1 > 0$. Then $-1 + 2 > 0 + 2$, i.e. $1 > 2$. And so on. Now you might object by saying “but I *happen* to know that $1$ is not greater than $2$, so here is a 'contradiction' ”. But you are taking for granted that, at some point, we will come across known truths that will produce a contradiction with our line of reasoning. Sometimes this is not so easily done. In fact, this is the idea, and the caveat, behind proof by contradiction. If you want to prove p, you can suppose that it is false, and then at some point of our reasoning we come across some known truths that produce a contradiction/conflict with our reasoning, so we can conclude that p cannot be false, i.e. it is true. But if you *don’t* come across any such contradictions/conflicts, you have not proven p, because there could be other contradictions/conflicts lurking out there that we just haven’t come across yet.

So, I suspect that what you mean to show is that *there are no counterexamples* to our claim that Cond implies p. This is fine. But that’s the hard part — show that there are no counterexamples. If you start out with *assuming* that there are no counterexamples, then there is nothing left to prove.

Sometimes it helps to sit down with the logical *definitions*. The definition of p implies q is $\neg p \vee q$, where “$\vee$” is the “inclusive or”. Therefore the negation of p implies q is $p \wedge \neg q$, where “$\wedge$” is “and”. In other words, to disprove p implies q, you have to show that you can have p true but q false. Equivalently, to *prove* p implies q, you have to show that you never have p true but q false. To take the above example: to disprove that “$x$ is a non-negative real number” implies “$x^2$ is negative”, we need only produce one counterexample (in this case, let $x = 2$). But if we wanted to show it is true, we can do so by showing that no such counterexamples exist. If we didn’t know that $2^2$ was not negative, or for that matter if we didn’t know anything about whether squares of non-negative real numbers were negative or not, then we might never be able to *produce* a counterexample to our claim. But this doesn’t *prove* our claim. Just because you failed to come up with a counterexample to the claim doesn’t necessarily mean you’ve proved the claim, unless you can prove that you’ve considered *all cases*, and showed that your claim is true under all cases — one might call this proof by exhaustion or proof by cases. This is also valid, since in this case we’ve “considered our entire universe” and showed that our claim is always true.

Answer (score 2):

A) Yes. In fact, intuitionistic logicians would argue that's the only kind of proof by contradiction you can do. If $\neg p$ implies a contradiction, $\neg\neg p$, but in intuitionistic logic this doesn't imply $p$.

B) You can deduce anything from a contradiction, so deducing something else doesn't prove anything.